# why I will print "NaN" in java?

Tags: java, file-processing

I pass a file into the method. Then, I read the method by line. After that, if the line fulfills my condition, I will read the line by token-based, and update i. My question is, from the output, It looks like my I do not successfully update because my output is NaN. Could you help me to take look at this method, and tell me is anywhere going wrong?

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class ReadingData {

    static Scanner console=new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args)throws FileNotFoundException{
        System.out.println("Please input a file name to input:");
        String name1=console.next();
        Scanner input=new Scanner(new File(name1));
        choosegender(input);    
    }

    public static void choosegender(Scanner input){
        boolean judge=false;
        while(judge==false) {
            System.out.println("Parse by gender(m/f/M/F):");
            String gender=console.next().toUpperCase();
            if(gender.contains("F")||gender.contains("M")) {
                count(input,gender);
                judge=true;  
            }else {
                System.out.println("Wrong...please select again!");
            }
        }
    }

    public static void count(Scanner input,String gender){
        int i=0;
        int totalage=0;

        while(input.hasNextLine()) {
            String line=input.nextLine();

            if(line.contains(gender)) { 
                Scanner token=new  Scanner(line);
                int id=token.nextInt();
                String name=token.next();
                String sex=token.next();
                int age=token.nextInt();
                i++;
                totalage=totalage+age;
           }
        }

        double average=(double)totalage/i;
        if(gender.equals("F")) {
            System.out.printf("the number of female is "+" "+i+",and the average age is %.1f\n ",average);
        }else {
            System.out.printf("the number of male is"+" "+i+",and the average age is %.1f\n",average);
        }
    }
}
```

My output is :

```
Please input a file name to input:
student.txt
Parse by gender(m/f/M/F):
f
the number of female is  0,and the average age is NaN
```

Comment: Hint: NaN means "not a number".  NaN values are created when you do a floating point mathematical operation that is meaningless; e.g. you divided zero by zero, or try to take the square root of a negative number.  That should be sufficient to allow you to debug your program.

Comment: First, it's better to separate calculations from code asking for user input. That's separation of concerns.

Comment: Are you sure there is some 'F' line in the file? Post a excerpt of the `student.txt` file.

Answer (score 0):

NaN stands for **Not a Number**.

In javadoc, the constant field NaN is declared as following in the Float and Double Classes respectively.

public static final float   NaN = 0f / 0f;
public static final double      NaN = 0d / 0d;

Answer (score 0):

If you divide a `float` or `double` number by `0`, you will get `NaN`(not a number, see the answer from @Anup Lal)

In your case, if there is no line that contains `gender`, `i` will be `0` and you average will be `NaN`.